# Concatenate rows of data to new dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with large sets of data in Python, by way of Pandas. I have a file containing identifiers of interest and a file of data with rows that may or may not match these identifiers.

I've written a piece of code that uses identifiers in the first file to find rows of data matching the identifier in the second file. This code presently outputs the rows of interest to the terminal (via "print"). I would like to load the rows of data my code finds into a DataFrame so that the output may be written to a csv file (via "pandas.to_csv"), but am unsure how to proceed.

This is the code at present:

```
for i in range(0, len(egg.index)):
#selects datum in file1 as search term
    identifier = egg.ix[i,0]
    for j in range(0, len(b.index)):
    #searches file2 for row indexed by identifier
        if identifier in b.ix[j, "SAMPLE_ID"]:
        print b.ix[j]
        #prints row to console
        outputdf = concat(b.ix[j])
        #should concatenate row to a fresh dataframe for output; fails
```

Thanks!

Comment: Edited the question to show my code.

Comment: show us some data. i don't think you even need to construct a second dataframe. we can probably just select the data and output directly to CSV

Comment: Hey Paul, I think you are correct; however, attempting to output a row of data directly to CSV results in each output overwriting the last. the row "b.ix[j]" can be written to CSV with `b.ix[j].to_csv(path)`, but I do not know how to append data to a CSV file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.to_csv(path, mode='a')
```

to append the row to the existing file.

(I wanted to put this to the comments to your question, but I don't have enough reputation to do that.)